# UIImageView image not crisp with UIViewContentModeAspectFit

Tags: iphone

I was under the impression that UIImageView scales your image accordingly, but I'm not sure if I understand it correctly.  So I have an image in two places, one smaller than the other.  In the area that is smaller, the picture is not crisp.  What I do for this small area is:

```
UIImageView *container = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
UIImageView *graphic = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10 , 120, 120)] autorelease];
[graphic setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
graphic.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[container addSubview:graphic];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(container.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    [container.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I basically have my graphic as a subview to the container.  Like an image on a playing card, and then this method returns the viewImage back to me.  But when I look at the image on the playing card, it is less crisp then the image elsewhere when I just have it in a larger imageview.  Is there a reason for this?  Thanks.

1st image, crisp:
[image]

2nd image, not as crisp:
[image]

Comment: Are you just using this method to resize an image? Can we take a step back and talk about your overall goal with this code, as there might be a standard way to achieve your needs.

Comment: @Sam As far as I know from being put on this project, the goal was to create a playing card feel with the image on top of a playing card.  I think they were trying to emulate Apple's coverflow with a playing card and some text.  So once the UIImageView is returned, they can then move it around on the canvas.  Does that help?  Thx again Sam.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You set a scaleFactor of `1.0` in your `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` call. This will result in your art being rendered at 50% size if you are running on a device with a retina screen. You can change `1.0` to `2.0` or better yet, get the scale factor from the `UIDevice` class.

Comment: I tried changing the scale factor, and the images still look the same.  The scale factor seems to render the whole bitmap, including the background container imageview I'm using.  I can see that by playing with the values (decreasing makes it really blocky).  When I increase the scale factor, it does not seem to make the graphic imageview any crisper though.  Is there something else I'm missing?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some sample images so we can get a closer look at the exact issue?

Comment: Additionally try setting the context up with a scale factor of 0. This should automatically select the most appropriate scale factor.

Comment: I added the images so you could see.  The pictures are with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(container.bounds.size, NO, 0);`

Comment: Try one more thing: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(container.bounds.size.width * 2.f, container.bounds.size.height * 2.f), NO, 0);`

Comment: That seems to shrink the container graphic that I was using for the pictures.  Well it shrinks the container graphic and everything inside of it.